# Spring/Thymeleaf - Bootstrap Calendar Integration - Templates Issues

Tags: spring, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, thymeleaf, saxparser

i wanted to integrate https://github.com/Serhioromano/bootstrap-calendar in my Spring web application.

So i set everything up as described - put the tmpls files in /tmpls folder and added following line to config, so there is no need for an explicit controller.

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/tmpls/*"/>
```

I get following error:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/*/tmpls/month.html 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

And thats because:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 3
ERROR org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine - [THYMELEAF][tomcat-http--31] Exception processing template "tmpls/month": Exception parsing document: template="tmpls/month", line 2 - column 3
```

there are alot of invalid characters used in those templates, according to the templateEngine.

```
Invalid character used in text string ( <% _.each(days_name, function(name){ %> ).
```

Is there anything i can do to make those templates work in my application?

- like wrapping this templates?

I'm really lost - and need kind of a hint where to go. I appreacite any help, thx.

Comment: i thougth about to rewrite this templates in .jsp/jstl and then add a second .jsp Servlet based on a JspResolver - but i dont know if its the right way go  and if there is a maybe much more easy solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this solution by now:

I added the tmpls folder to my application:

```
WEB-INF/thymeleaf/tmpls
```

I added follwing line to config, so there is no need for an explicit controller.

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/tmpls/*"/>
```

I added a second JSP-based Servlet and JSPResolver:

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>JSP_Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>
     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
  </servlet-class>
  <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/spring/jsp-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>JSP_Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/jsp/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

jsp-config.xml:

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/thymeleaf/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
</bean>
```

then in the frontend:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function() {
         var calendar = $("#calendar").calendar(
         {
           tmpl_path: "../jsp/tmpls/",
           events_source: function () { return []; }
         });  
     });

</script>
```

Templates are shown correct. Actions seem to be fine.

I dont know if there is a more clean and easy solution out there since chaining servlets may not be the best idea. For me it's okay by now.